# Storing test results with images and applying validation

Tags: database, images, web, validation

I am looking for software that will let me store test results.

Now these results consist of attributes as well as specific values. The values need to be greater than a static value determined by selections made previously OR based on a value procured from another database / spreadsheet that tells it what to compare against.

Each test will have 3 samples consisting of 3 images that would need to be stored hopefully linked to the tests results.

Currently they are using excel to document the test results and storing the files separately  in a folder.

They do have Microsoft Access which could be used. Looking for other free / open source software that could be used that would be best suited for this.

Also will need to be able to give access to people over the web to be able to add to these test results.

There will be some post processing work that will eventually be required, e.g. same test result being submitted where the older one is archived etc.

Comment: "people over the web": Anyone on the web can submit test results? Or only people with a valid username/password?

Comment: How are the "attributes as well as specific values" generated? Do people enter them themselves in a web form? Do you have a kind of GUI, and if yes with what technologies?

Comment: The organisation has a method of granting access I believe it's called covisint.

Comment: The GUI to input this data will have to be generated. The values will be entered by the individuals via the form.

Comment: There are times when I wish this was a contract job bidding board ....